# Spring MVC MultipartFile. Сохранения изображений в проекте

Tags: файлы, tomcat, spring-mvc

Я для сохранения изображений использую класс MultipartFile. Но изображения сохраняются на локальном ПК(ноутбуке), и для того, чтобы они в принципе подтягивались нужно было настроить сам Tomcat. Отсюда возникает вопрос: когда проект будет запущен и размещен на сервере, позволит ли мне хост ( или кто там ) сохранять изображения локально на их сервере ? Правильный ли это подход для сохранения изображений и можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы картинки сохранялись в самом проекте? И если ни один из этих вариантов не подходит, то возможно кто-то знает как правильно настроить систему сохранения изображений в проекте, чтобы все правильно работало после его релиза.
Собственно сервис который работает с файлами, и пример того, как они сохраняются в контроллере:

```
@Override
public String saveFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, String path) {

    String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
    String location = SAVE_LOCATION+path+"/";
    File pathFile = new File(location);
    if (!pathFile.exists()) {
        pathFile.mkdir();
    }

    pathFile = new File(location + fileName);
    try {
        multipartFile.transferTo(pathFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location+multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value="updatePl",  method = RequestMethod.POST )
public String updateByOperator(PlaceForm placeForm, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult result){
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
    MultipartFile multipartFile = multipartRequest.getFile("file");
    Place place = placeService.getById(placeForm.getPlaceId());
    place.setName(placeForm.getName());
    place.setFile(fileService.saveFile(multipartFile, "place"));
    placeService.update(place);
    return "redirect:editOperator";
}
```

Изменения, которые были внесены в server.xml Tomcat:

```
  <Context path="/image/" docBase="C:/image/" crossContext="false" debug="0" reloadable="true" privileged="true" />
```

Comment: что в твоём случае такое `placeService`?

Comment: это сервис, который работает с объектом Place (заведения).

Comment: это что-то из сторонней библиотеки или самописная вещь?

Comment: самописная. это обычный сервис  с набором круд операций, который работает  с моделью, одним из полей которой есть изображения. Этот контроллер просто пример того, как оно сохраняется. Но вся логика  сохранения описана в сервисе и xml конфигурации томката.

Answer (score 3):

1. Можно ли сохранять картинки внутри самого приложения?

Технически можно, фактически не стоит.

2. Какие есть наилучшие пути решения проблемы?

Во-первых можно сохранять картинки в базу, где в одной из колонок хранить дескриптор файла.

Во-вторых можно сделать jndi-переменную на сервере, которая будет отдавать путь к папке, в которую сервер разрешает сохранять файлы. Для tomcat'а в файл `context.xml` нужно добавить следующее:

```
<Context>
   ....
    <Environment name="fileStorage/basePath" value="путь_к_папке_для_сохранения" type="java.lang.String"/>
   ....
</Context>
```

Внедрить данную переменную в spring-бин можно так

```
 @Resource(mappedName = "fileStorage/basePath")
 private String basePath;
```

Однако тут есть два подводных камня. Первый - у тебя (у пользователя под которым крутится java-сервер) должны быть права на запись в данную папку на уровне системы. Особенно стоит обратить на это внимание, если сервер крутится на linux. Второе - то, что сам сервер может быть запущен в защищенном режиме. Явление редкое (по умолчанию в tomcat'е отключено), но встречается (к примеру в WebSphere AS включено по умолчанию). Соответственно здесь надо права настраивать уже на уровне `java policy`.

И в-третьих можно написать утилитку, которую можно внедрять при помощи того же jndi, с соответствующим интерфейсом. Но это уже задача со звёздочкой, т.к. под каждый тип сервера придётся писать свою фабрику и т.д. Плюс, это не избавить тебя от проблем с правами при написании данной утилиты.

Comment: насколько оптимально сохранять изображения в базе?

Comment: @khodan.D. на этот вопрос общего ответа нет. Но в многих случая именно так и делают.

Comment: тогда такой вопрос? можно ли как-то в spring mvc + hibernate кешировать изображения на клиенте, чтобы при повторной перезагрузке страницы они выгружались более быстрей?

Comment: @khodan.D. Это уже вопрос не по теме. Задавай отдельным вопросом. Вообще `hibernate` поддерживает кеш третьего уровня (аля кеш запросов). Если его включить, то blob'ы вполне могут кэшироваться. Тут надо поэкспериментировать. На крайний случай можно сделать свой Map ([пример](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6400874/5506820)) с кэшем, где в качестве ключей использовать время последнего обращения.